# junit5 parallel execution doesn't work through ConsoleLauncher

Tags: junit, junit5

Based on the JUnit5 console launcher [docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher), it seems there isn't a way to configure parallel execution. Does ConsoleLauncher not support parallel execution yet or should setting the config in junit-platform.properties be enough?

I tried using the ConsoleLauncher (set parallel mode in junit-platform.properties) but the tests still seem to be running sequentially. I am able to run them in parallel via Gradle though.

Comment: Have you tried `--config command-line option` ? Maybe with these two parameters `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true` and 
`junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent` - I post it as a comment because I can't reproduce for now

Comment: you're right, I had to add specific config while invoking the ConsoleLauncher.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by adding specific config while invoking the ConsoleLauncher

- *-Djunit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true*
- *-Djunit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent*

Ref: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params